# Discord.js check for a user mention inside a message

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I have this code:

```js
const args = message.content.split(" ");
args.shift();
var mention = message.mentions.users.first()
const subject = args[0];
        
        
if (!subject) {
  return message.say(`*you wand projects a stream of water*`)
} else if (subject === mention) {
  return message.say(`*Your wand projects a stream of water at ${mention} and they are now soaked*`)
```

and I am trying to get it to pick up the `mention.users.first()` variable called `mention` so people can specify to shoot the spell at someone. I can't quite figure out how to get it to be checked. I've tried a couple of things like:

```js
} else if (subject === mention) {
} else if (subject === 'mention') {
} else if (subject === {mention}) {
```

I knew this one probably wouldn't work but I tried it:

```js
} else if (subject === ${mention}) {
```

I can't figure out if I'm not wording it properly or if it is just the wrong way to do entirely. Any pointers or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well a role mention in `<Message>.content` would take the form of `<@&ID>`, it will be a sstring, discord.js already has a static property of the regex needed to validate role mentions which is: `/<@&(\d{17,19})>/g`, so now you just have to test if the string passes:

```js
const regex = /<@&(\d{17,19})>/g;
if(regex.test(subject)) {

}
```

Also like I said you can get this regex by the static property
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=s-ROLES_PATTERN

```js
const {MessageMentions} = require("discord.js");
const regex = MessageMentions.ROLES_PATTERN;
```

Comment: when i try and test i get discord api errors "DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length."

Comment: Anyhow that error is occurring when you do something like `message.say("string");`, most likely you have a variable instead and it's surpassing 2000 characters, in which case you will need to truncate it.